# Lettered List in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks with python 3 kernel. I know how to make a numbered list, but how do I make a lettered list? For the numbered list I just type `1.` and then a space after. So to make a numbered list with three items, I would type

```
 1. typing item one
 1. typing item two
 1. typing item three
```

and that would give me

1. typing item one
2. typing item two
3. typing item three

So is there a similar way to get an output of

a. typing item one
b. typing item two
c. typing item three

Comment: Jupyter notebook uses Markdown in non code cells, I dont think its possible to have lettered lists in markdown

Comment: @hilton92 Got it. So I **cannot** do this. This is strange because it seems like such a simple thing, but yet it can't be done. Thanks for your help.